# Is there a way in Stable baseline 3 to introduce decay parameter in the gaussian noise used in DDPG implementation?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, noise, ddpg, decay

Is there a way in Stable baseline 3 to introduce decay parameter in the gaussian noise used in DDPG implementation ?

I want the noise whether the OU Noise or Gaussian noise to decay with the episodes for the policy to learn faster .